# WCF: Client config for non-.net-clients

Tags: wcf

I am developing a `wcf` service (`basicHttpBinding`) that should also be consumed by non .net clients (e.g. Java clients). But now I wonder how the client can define his client config file. Or is this file only needed for .net-clients? (I am thinking of configurations like `maxReceivedMessageSize` or `maxItemsInObjectGraph` for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each development platform (call it as you want: SOAP stack, Framework, API) has its own way to configure communication. You don't need to bother with it. You just need to expose correct WSDL and client's developer will be responsible for configuring the client application based on his needs.

If you want to extend documentation of your service in WSDL you can use `wsdl:documentation`. WCF doesn't offer it by default but you can use [this technology sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717040.aspx) to extend WCF. You can use such documentation for example to describe that service operation can return large amount of data. Another approach to add `wsdl:documentation` is using [WCF Extras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, the client shouldn't have access to those configuration options.  For instance, why should a client to the WCF service be able to specify the maxReceivedMessageSize?

What you probably want to do is define these configuration options on the server-side.  If a client makes a call and there is a conflict with one of your options (i.e. the client exceeds maxReceivedMessageSize), you'll want to throw a SoapException back to the client.

If you want to let the client have access to the configuration settings before he or she sends a request, you can always implement a simple web service method that sends back the values.